# how to submit the same forms in one page in django

Tags: django, form-submit, nested-forms

I am struggling how to submit multiple the same forms in one page.
I have 3 model classes:

1. Group_attribut
2. Attribute
3. Attribut_items

I create this form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Attribute, Attribute_Item


class GroupAttrForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group_attribute
        fields = ('title', 'catId', 'slug', 'display_order',)


class AttForm(forms.ModelForm):
    list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Attribute_Item.objects.all(),
        label='items list'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('title', 'type', 'slug', 'group_attributeId',)
```

I want to use this form while creating `Group_attribut` - with on click save the group and its Attributes with their all `Attribut_items` - page is something like: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OX5B.jpg]

please help me